# TypeScript: Narrow down function return value type based on the actual return value type

Tags: typescript

Assume I have an object containing indexed functions of two kinds:

```ts
type StringReturningFn<ItemType> = (item: ItemType) => string;
type NumberReturningFn<ItemType> = (item: ItemType) => number;

type FunctionIndex<ItemType, Index extends string> = {
    [key in Index]: StringReturningFn<ItemType> | NumberReturningFn<ItemType>;
}

const myIndex: FunctionIndex<...> = {
   // ... some functions ...
}
```

Later in the code I obtain a function from this index. I want to call it several times and I need to know, which one of the two kinds of functions I have. I thought that I should be able to narrow down the return type by type checking on any (first) return value type. But this does not work:

```ts
const currentFn = myIndex[someIndex];

const resultA = currentFn(itemA); // resultA: string | number
const resultB = currentFn(itemA); // resultB: string | number

if (typeof resultA === 'string') {
   // resultB: string | number, although it obviously cannot be number now
}
```

Is this type narrowing somehow possible? If not, is it by design, or is it a typescript bug that might be (will be?) fixed? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproducible example? I'm unable to reproduce with [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3nNBXCGAXPJjAJYoDm8APvCrgLYBGIMA3ALABQPZAZvAAUGAJ4AHEEkE58WALyL4AIlIVKygJTwA3j3gHsIPAQB0aCGTAIA9Dfj8KIHvsOyzGJADEyADxDA8Hb0SFiOKM7cAL5AA)

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gJ2BBBhOA7AZgSwOYA8AksgLYAq4EANLIsEQCZQQAeyGjAzlF8Ajgx4AfFAC8UAN4BYAFBQFUANpd6TKILpImAXQBcUABSGcZAyQgUqASnGi+AodYA+x05fNlKkW2NEYAV1IAIxRrAG45AF85OQBjTD4oAAsAQ04AGwh0bHxxKGIvKlp4bWY2Dm5efkERQwTcvANS5DRMXEILK0gStUZhWlUy5r7fURl5RQakoeB8kzIAQU9LbxoNMgAhFe6IMak5RSOoabm4gIQECAxgHI78ho6VPp1IyeOTxLmAN1SMgIgiweFyuNzu+AWlkWEUOH0+GCSv3+EE2wMu11u7Qh7lImxhslhHxwWCMoEgcBJSIBQLEtKgAHIHLV6bYJnDjlTAQA6DJwOJ-bJwUhgVJXQycvHhKAAemlvGScACGWYoSgcAA1rRggE5jguBh6cBCccYu8oKbTUA) @hhearts

Comment: TypeScript simply does not have any mechanisms to detect relations like this. To TypeScript, `resultA` and `resultB` are totally unrelated, so checking `resultA` does not affect `resultB`.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately TypeScript does not generally narrow function types based on the type of their output.  The easiest thing for you to do is assert that `resultB` is `string`.  If you care about the compiler providing more safety, you'll need to refactor `SorterConfig<T>` into a discriminated union type. See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKyXzN) for those options.  If this fully addresses your question I could write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, @TobiasS, I thought that was the case.

Comment: @jcalz Your solutions are exactly what I used in the meantime, thank you! I didn't like the discriminated union type solution so much, because it puts more demands on the input side and I wanted it to be simple and straightforward. In the end I am happy with the "forced" assertion, from the code it is clear that this assertion will always succeed so I will probably leave it like this.